# Using the _syscall macro for user-space application

Tags: kernel, system-calls

I have seen this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

#define __NR_getjiffies     320
#define __NR_diffjiffies    321
#define __NR_pdiffjiffies   322

_syscall0( long, getjiffies );
_syscall1( long, diffjiffies, long, ujiffies );
_syscall2( long, pdiffjiffies, long, ujiffies, long*, presult );

int main()
{
  long jifs, result;
  int err;

  jifs = getjiffies();

  printf( "difference is %lx\n", diffjiffies(jifs) );

  err = pdiffjiffies( jifs, &result );

  if (!err) {
     printf( "difference is %lx\n", result );
  } else {
     printf( "error\n" );
  }

     return 0;
 }
```

I have two questions:

- I'm wondering to know why one needs to use system call for finding the difference between two number?
- In generall when do we need to use syscall?

Answer (score 0):

**why one needs to use system call for finding the difference between two number?** - I have no idea where you have seen this code, but you certainly can use a simple minus to calculate how much time elapsed.

**Why we need syscalls?** - Because since the 1982 processors use something called 'protected mode', which means that the CPU is hardwired to give you limited access to stuff, while it runs in protected mode. So every time you want to use hardware (print to the screen, write to a file, send something through network card, etc.) you cannot do this in protected mode. So you use system calls to ask the kernel to do it for you (the kernel does not run in protected mode), and the kernel may do it, may report a problem or just tell you that you have no permissions. So, in a nutshell: You need system calls to do privileged stuff like using hardware.